# Prevent Delphi IDE creating component icons at design time

Tags: delphi, custom-controls

I have created a custom control TOuterControl that is the parent for multiple TInnerControls.

Everything is working fine except that the IDE is creating icons for each the child TInnerControl's (InnerControl1 and InnerControl2 in the screenshot). How do I prevent the IDE from generating the icons?

[image]

```
unit TestControl;

interface

Procedure Register;

implementation

Uses
    Classes,
    Controls,
    SysUtils,
    DesignEditors,
    DesignIntf,
    VCLEditors;

Type

TOuterControl = Class;

TInnerControl = Class(TComponent)
Protected
    FOuterControl : TOuterControl;

    function GetParentComponent: TComponent; Override;
    Function HasParent : Boolean; Override;
    procedure SetParentComponent                  (Value: TComponent); Override;
End;

TOuterControl = Class(TCustomControl)
Protected
    FInnerControls : TList;

    Procedure Paint; Override;
Public
    Constructor Create(AOwner : TComponent); Override;
    Procedure AddInnerControl(AInnerControl : TInnerControl);
    procedure GetChildren(Proc: TGetChildProc; Root: TComponent); override;
End;

TOuterControlEditor = Class(TDefaultEditor)
Public
    Procedure ExecuteVerb(Index : Integer);          Override;
    Function  GetVerb    (Index : Integer) : String; Override;
    Function  GetVerbCount      : Integer;           Override;
End;

procedure TOuterControl.AddInnerControl(AInnerControl: TInnerControl);
begin
    AInnerControl.FOuterControl := Self;;
    FInnerControls.Add(AInnerControl);
    Invalidate;
end;

constructor TOuterControl.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
    inherited;

    FInnerControls := TList.Create;
end;

procedure TOuterControl.GetChildren(Proc: TGetChildProc; Root: TComponent);
var
    I : Integer;
begin
    inherited;

    For I := 0 To FInnerControls.Count - 1 Do
        Proc(FInnerControls[I]);
end;

procedure TOuterControl.Paint;
begin
    inherited;

    Canvas.FillRect(ClientRect);
    Canvas.TextOut(0,0, Format('Inner Control Count = %d', [FInnerControls.Count]));
end;

function TInnerControl.GetParentComponent: TComponent;
begin
    Result := FOuterControl;
end;

function TInnerControl.HasParent: Boolean;
begin
    Result := True;
end;

procedure TInnerControl.SetParentComponent(Value: TComponent);
begin
    If Value Is TOuterControl Then
        If FOuterControl <> Value Then
    Begin
        FOuterControl := TOuterControl(Value);
        FOuterControl.AddInnerControl(Self);
    End;
end;

procedure TOuterControlEditor.ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer);
Var
    OuterControl : TOuterControl;
    InnerControl : TInnerControl;
begin
    inherited;

    OuterControl := TOuterControl(Component);

    If Index = 0 Then
    Begin
        InnerControl := TInnerControl.Create(OuterControl.Owner);
        OuterControl.AddInnerControl(InnerControl);
    End;
end;

function TOuterControlEditor.GetVerb(Index: Integer): String;
begin
    Result := 'Add Inner';
end;

function TOuterControlEditor.GetVerbCount: Integer;
begin
    Result := 1;
end;

Procedure Register;
Begin
    RegisterComponents('AA', [TOuterControl]);
    RegisterComponentEditor(TOuterControl, TOuterControlEditor);
End;


Initialization
    Classes.RegisterClasses([TInnerControl]);

end.
```

Comment: It looks like you're re-inventing `TCollection`. Make the inner "controls" descend from `TCollectionItem`, define a small `TOwnedCollection` descendant for the outer control to have, and all your design-time management tasks will be solved.

Comment: Using TCollectionItem and TOwnedCollection does not make sense in my situation, the code i posted is a cut down example.

Comment: Why does it not make sense?  What are you trying to accomplish that TCollection/TCollectionItem cannot handle exactly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can prevent them from appeaing on the form with:

```
RegisterNoIcon([TInnerControl]);
```

More info on RegisterNoIcon can be found at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/e/index.php/Classes.RegisterNoIcon

It's a little confusing having classes with a name that end with "Control" that aren't normal visual controls though.

Comment: +1 for not mentioning the "RegisterNoIcon" phrase being confusing as well -- because we do not "register no icon", but we do register without an component palette icon. RegisterWithoutIcon or even RegisterComponentsWithoutIcon would have been more self-documenting.

Comment: As someone who voted up this answer for *not* mentioning the confusing name, @TheBlast, you sure talk a lot about the confusing name.

Comment: SetSubComponent() is the correct approach.  RegisterNoIcon() may have a useful side effect (I'm not sure that it does, I haven't tested) but does not actually, technically, do what is required (except by accident, in which case it may legitimately stop doing it at some point).

Comment: @Rob -- yeah, got it: I talk too much.

Answer (score 6):

If TInnerControl is meant to be used only inside a TOuterControl, then you should call SetSubComponent(True) during/after the TInnerControl's creation.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was not accepted as the right answer.  This is the correct answer.  I can only think that RegisterNoIcon may have a useful side-effect (I haven't tested to see if that is the case).

Answer (score 4):

When you create the inner controls, you tell them that their owner is the form (the owner of the outer control). Therefore, the form draws them, just like it draws all the other components it owns. You probably want the outer control to own the inner ones.